# How to merge the lines starting with specific substring?

Tags: unix, awk, printf, substr

I have a file like this

```
$ head test
                     gene=ENSECAG00000012421
                     note="synaptonemal complex central element protein 1
                     [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:28852]"
                     gene=ENSECAG00000017803
                     note="Uncharacterized protein
                     [Source:UniProtKB/TrEMBL;Acc:F6SNR9]"
                     gene=ENSECAG00000019088
                     note="cytochrome P450 2E1  [Source:RefSeq
                     peptide;Acc:NP_001104773]"
                     gene=ENSECAG00000004229
```

And I would like it to look like to get this file to look like this

```
ENSECAG00000012421    synaptonemal complex central element protein 1 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:28852]
ENSECAG00000017803    Uncharacterized protein [Source:UniProtKB/TrEMBL;Acc:F6SNR9]
```

I'm not sure if note is always in two lines, so I would like something along the lines of

```
awk '{if(substr($1,1,4)=="gene") gene=$1; else print gene,$1}'
```

But I would like it to recognize that it might be in two lines and also that there are spaces in between th words. So I would like it to print everything that's in " " as column 2 (and ideally seperating the 2 columns by \t, so that it doesn't get mixed up later)
I know how to get rid of gene and note and the ", but wasn't sure if they might be helpful for identification. 
I'm happy for it to be a string of different commands, first putting the entire note in one line and then combining it with gene or everything in one go, whatever works best.

Also, if you are using awk, could you give a short explanation of what you are doing?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `GNU awk` or `mawk` (the solution relies on an input record separator based on a regex, which strictly POSIX-compliant or older `awk` implementations do not support):

**Short version:**

```
awk -v RS=' *(gene=|note="|")' '
  { gsub("\n", ""); if ($0 == "") next; $1=$1; 
    printf "%s%s", $0, (/^ENSECAG[0-9]+$/ ? "\t" : "\n") }
  ' file
```

**Annotated version:**

`-v RS=' *(gene=|note="|")'` - `RS` is a special variable that defines the input Record Separator - specifies a regex that breaks the input into records of interest - across lines.

```
awk -v RS=' *(gene=|note="|")' '
  {    
   gsub("\n", "");     # remove all newlines from record
   if ($0 == "") next  # ignore empty records
   $1=$1;              # rebuild record to compress multiple interior spaces
    # Output:
    #  - Is it a gene record, i.e. is there only 1 field that contains a gene name?
    #    Output it with just a trailing \t, but no trailing \n, so that the next
    #    note record will print on the same line.
    #  - Otherwise: a note record: print with trailing \n, effectively
    #    appending it to the previous gene record.
   printf "%s%s", $0, (/^ENSECAG[0-9]+$/ ? "\t" : "\n")
  }
  ' file
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and also your explanation! Your code works great for lines where note spans over 2 lines, however when note="processed_pseudogene" it gets confused, e.g. 

/gene=ENSECAG00000005298
/note="processed_pseudogene"
/gene=ENSECAG00000026864
/note="cyclic nucleotide binding domain containing 1
[Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:26663]"
turns into:
ENSECAG00000005298      ENSECAG00000026864      cyclic nucleotide binding domain containing 1 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:26663]

Comment: /gene=ENSECAG00000026236
/note="U6 spliceosomal RNA [Source:RFAM;Acc:RF00026]"

which is also only 2 lines is processed correctly
ENSECAG00000026236      U6 spliceosomal RNA [Source:RFAM;Acc:RF00026]

Comment: @user3400409: My code made the - mistaken - assumption that any record containing only 1 field is by definition a gene line. The solution is to examine the _contents_ of that a record to determine whether it is a gene name. I don't know how specific that test can/should be, but I've updated my answer to replace the too-broad test (NF==1) with a specific, regex-based one. NOTE: The original non-empty-line test `/\S/` inexplicably doesn't work with one-line note records in older `gawk`/`mawk` versions, so I've had to rewrite the awk program a bit; hope it works for you now.

Comment: Thank you! there was another bug, but that was my fault, since I didn't realize my /note could also spanning 3 lines, once my test file greped the right thing, your command worked perfectly for 3 lines as well! Also, all of my gene names start with ENSECAG followed by numbers, so that's broad enough for my example. Cheers!

Comment: @user3400409: My pleasure; I'm glad we worked it out in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Probably over-complicated, but here's one way:

```
/^\s*gene=/  { gene=substr($1, 6) }
/^\s*note=/  { note=substr($0, 28) }
/"$/         { if (substr($1,1,4)=="note")
                 print gene, substr($0, 28, length($0)-28);
               else
                 print gene, note, substr($0, 22, length($0)-22) }
```

Notice that this handles both one- and two-line notes.

Comment: This works for the specific input (except that the OP wants a `\t` rather than a space after the 1st output token), but doesn't generalize well; you can make this more portable by using `[[:space:]]` instead of `\s`.

Comment: @mklement0, Your answer (which I like very much) is also for the "specific input" (it contains the words "note" and "gene", for instance).

Comment: Thanks (I wish my answer worked with all `awk`s, but it doesn't); what I was referring to are the hard-coded character positions in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\n";RS="gene="}{gsub(/(note=|\")/,"");print $1,$2,$3}' file|awk '$1=$1'

ENSECAG00000012421 synaptonemal complex central element protein 1 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:28852]
ENSECAG00000017803 Uncharacterized protein [Source:UniProtKB/TrEMBL;Acc:F6SNR9]
ENSECAG00000019088 cytochrome P450 2E1 [Source:RefSeq peptide;Acc:NP_001104773]
ENSECAG00000004229
```

Comment: Close, but the OP wants a `\t` to separate the gene name from the note (i.e., to have only *2* output columns, separated by `\t`). Requires `gawk` or `mawk` due to use of multi-char. `RS`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 sed -n 'N;;/"$/!N;s/\n//g;p' input | \
   sed 's/.*gene=//;s/[ \t]*note="\([^"]*\)"/\t\1 /;s/  */ /g'
```

*Gives:*

```
ENSECAG00000012421  synaptonemal complex central element protein 1 [Source:HGN...
ENSECAG00000017803  Uncharacterized protein [Source:Uni...
ENSECAG00000019088  cytochrome P450 2E1 [Source:Ref...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{$1=$1; gsub(/"/,""); sub(/^note=/,""); pfx=(sub(/^gene=/,"")?(NR>1?ORS:""):OFS); printf "%s%s",pfx,$0} END{print ""}' file
ENSECAG00000012421 synaptonemal complex central element protein 1 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:28852]
ENSECAG00000017803 Uncharacterized protein [Source:UniProtKB/TrEMBL;Acc:F6SNR9]
ENSECAG00000019088 cytochrome P450 2E1 [Source:RefSeq peptide;Acc:NP_001104773]
ENSECAG00000004229
```

Comment: Close, but the OP wants a `\t` to separate the gene name from the note (i.e., to have only *2* output columns, separated by `\t`).